# Accessing File from ClassPath

Tags: java, maven, jar

In my Maven project:

```
src/main/java/App  --> has Main
src/main/resources/file.json
```

.

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        URL url = App.class.getClass().getResource("/file.json");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

As I understand these Maven [docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR), I should be able to access `file.json` as it (should be) on the classpath since it's located at `src/main/resources`.

But, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on the `url.getPath()` call.

Comment: Have you tried it without the leading `/` ?

Comment: I always use the class loader's `getResource()` method.  Also, how are you executing `App.main`?

Comment: FYI `File file = new File(url.getPath());` is not a good idea, as the contents of the `resources` directory are likely to be included in your Jar, which is the next thing to check.  What does your Jar contain?

Comment: Normally I would assume that you get a `NullPointer` on the `new File()`call, which would make sense if the path is wrong or the File does not exist respectively. But as you pointed out, the error occurs while calling `url.getPath()`. Maybe you could check the url, if it's actually `NULL`, then there is the problem. If it's not NULL, I would log the url and see where it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing App.class.getClass() which is going to get the root classloader (java.lang.Class's classloader), which isn't the same as your application classloader.  You want to do App.class.getResource() instead.

Comment: After making your change, I ran `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.mycompany.app.App` to run the program. Initially I tried to execute the spit-out JAR, but realized it was simpler to run it per the command above. I got a `ClassDefNotFound` error due to an insufficient CLASSPATH env var.